# Why does this code give Vector out of range error?

Tags: c++

So I have this code where I'm trying to reverse a vector of strings (I know there are better ways, this is part of a project). I'm getting vector out of bounds error (my guess is that it occurs in the function loop part), what changes should I make to run this code properly?

```
//reversing a string

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<std::string> strvector;
strvector reverse (strvector &vec);

int main()
{
 strvector string;
 std::string a;
 std::cout << "Enter strings type esc to stop" << '\n';
 while (true)
 {
   std::cin >> a;
   if (a=="esc")
   break;
   string.push_back(a);
 }
 strvector reversed = reverse(string);
 std::cout << reversed.size();
  for (auto i:reversed)
  std::cout << ":" << i << ":" ;
}

//===-===-===-Functions-===-===-===//


strvector reverse (strvector &vec)
{   
 std::string temp;
 for (int i =0;i<vec.size();i++)
 {
    temp = vec.at(i);
    vec.at(i)=vec.at(i+1);
    vec.at(i+1)=temp;
 }
 return vec;
}
```

Comment: `vec.at(i)=vec.at(i+1);`  Think about it.

Comment: Please make your code readable. After you paste it, select it and press Ctrl+K.

Comment: Unrelated: In modern C++ `typedef std::vector<std::string> strvector;` can be `using strvector = std::vector<std::string>;` which is often easier to understand when syntax you're aliasing gets more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
vec.at(i)=vec.at(i+1);
```

Accesses an element beyond the end.  Not a good idea to add +1 to an index that already goes to the end of the vector :-)

Also, the reverse function passes by reference and then returns the vector that was passed by reference.  It is probably good to do one or the other.

This reverse function uses rbegin() and rend() to initialize a new vector.

Finally, I find that if I use getline(cin, input_line), I avoid a lot of errors that I run into when trying to read data directly into variables.  The more input cases you handle, the more often you will find this helpful.

Sorry for changing the typedefs back to std::vectorstd::string.  I was having trouble following the code and needed to name the variables in a way that I could keep them in my mind.  I try to avoid single character variable names.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


std::vector<std::string>  reverse (std::vector<std::string>  vec)
{
  return std::vector<std::string> (vec.rbegin(), vec.rend());
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<std::string> string_vector;
  std::string input_line;
  std::cout << "Enter strings type esc to stop" << '\n';
  while (std::getline(std::cin, input_line) && input_line != "esc")
  {
    string_vector.push_back(input_line);
  }
  
  std::vector<std::string>  reversed = reverse(string_vector);
  std::cout << reversed.size();
  for (auto element:reversed)
    std::cout << ":" << element << ":" ;
}
```

Comment: you are welcome.  You will find that the pattern shown here for using getline() is even more valuable when you combine it with std::stringstream for parsing individual lines.  See for example this answer:  [finding substrings with divide and conquer - look at alternative solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55516233/4983398).  Notice how the `while (token_stream >> token) ` parses tokens word by word from an input line.